# xcode iPhone array and dictionary [noob]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays

I'm sorry for this (*probably very*) noob question, but i've been asked about this and can't see what's wrong (i'm java tought..)
This is what I have, data is loaded via JSON:

```
NSDictionary *myvalues = [myres objectForKey:@"0"];
```

this is the content if I output via NSLog:

```
({id = "1a";myval = 5;},
 {id = "2b";myval="24.6";})
```

how do I iterate through myvalues and how do I get the values `id` and `myval`? Something like this i'm getting stuck:

```
for (NSArray* myvals_array in myvalues)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it looks like the returned value is an Array, the content inside of the parentheses() denotes this. So I would try and set it as such instead of a Dictionary. Then you can enumerate through the array of dictionary's and get each dictionary inside:

```
 for (id object in myvalues) {
        NSDictionary *currentObject = (NSDictionary*)object;
        NSString *myID = [currentObject valueForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *myValue  = [currentObject valueForKey:@"myval"];
        NSLog(@"ID:%@   VALUE:%@",myID,myValue);
    }
```

This will enumerate through the array and create a dictionary for each entry, then get the values for each of the two elements inside. I just NSLog() them here but you can do whatever you want with the values.